# How to retrieve the old and new values of a store state

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

In my component I am trying to get the old value and new value of a particular array of objects that is assigned in the vuex store state as followed. However when I newArray and oldArray return the same array of objects.

I understand from the documentation the following but I dont understand what is the best way to retrieve the different versions.

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

here how I am trying to do it right now in the component

```
export default {
  name: 'O1_OrderBook',
  watch: {
      '$store.state.orderBookSell': {
         deep: true,
         handler (newArray, oldArray) {
           console.log(newArray,oldArray)
         }
       }
    },
}
```

Comment: actually, what are you trying to do in the watcher? could find an easier way if i know what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let say when you create an array/object in Javascript,

```
 var arr = [1,2,3];
```

This creates an array in the browser's memory. But what `arr` variable contains is not the entire array value, it contains the reference to the array in browser memory. You could think of it as `arr` contains an address that can point you to the real array value in browser's memory.

if you do

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = arr;
arr2[0] = 4;
console.log(arr); // you would get [4,2,3];
```

editing `arr2` changed `arr` too. Because they both point to the same array in browser memory.

That's what "***the old value will be the same as the new value because they reference the same Object/Array***" means.

The same principle applies to object as well. In Javascript, an array is just a special type of object.

---

to retrieve the different versions of the array in the watcher, you must clone it to set it as a new array everytime you mutate it.

for e.g.,

```
state.orderBookSell = [...state.orderBookSell];
```

BUT..... `[...array]` is shallow cloning, not deep cloning. And that's a problem. You have an array of objects. Remember that object also have the same rules. They are passed by reference. So you gotta do a deep clone, so that all  the objects is cloned as well.

using [lodash cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) method for deep cloning

```
state.orderBookSell = _.cloneDeep(state.orderBookSell);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jacobs answer this is what I re-arranged in my component as to get it to work.

I created a computed variable in the component that deepClones the particular state array of objects.

```
computed: {
    orders () {
      return _.cloneDeep(this.$store.state.theArray)
    },
  },
```

and then setup a watch for that computed variable

```
watch: {
    orders (newValue,oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue,oldValue)
    }
  }
```