# Vue watch array (or object) push same old and new values

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuexfire

I'm using Vuex and I've created a module called claims that looks like this:

```js
import to from 'await-to-js'
import { functions } from '@/main'
import Vue from 'vue'

const GENERATE_TX_SUCCESS = 'GENERATE_TX_SUCCESS'
const GENERATE_TX_ERROR = 'GENERATE_TX_ERROR'

export default {
  state: [ ],
  mutations: {
    [GENERATE_TX_SUCCESS] (state, generateTxData) {
      state.push({ transaction: { ...generateTxData } })
    },
    [GENERATE_TX_ERROR] (state, generateTxError) {
      state.push({ transaction: { ...generateTxError } })
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async generateTx ({ commit }, data) {
      const [generateTxError, generateTxData] = await to(functions.httpsCallable('generateTx')(data))
      if (generateTxError) {
        commit(GENERATE_TX_ERROR, generateTxError)
      } else {
        commit(GENERATE_TX_SUCCESS, generateTxData)
      }
    }
  },
  getters: { }
}
```

Then, in the .vue component I do have this watch:

```js
 watch: {
    claims: {
      handler (newTxData, oldTxData) {
        console.log(newTxData)
      }
    }
 }
```

The problem I'm facing here is that newTxData is the same as oldTxData.

From my understanding, since this is a push and it detects the change, it's not one of these caveats: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

So basically the problem is this one:

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

Then my question is: how should I workaround this in the mutation?

**Edit**:

I tried also with `Vue.set(state, state.length, generateTxData)` but got the same behaviour.

**Edit 2** - *temporary solution* - (bad performance-wise):

I'm adapting [@matthew (thanks to @Jacob Goh)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50538743/5599288) to my solution with [vuexfire](https://github.com/posva/vuexfire):

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    claims: state => cloneDeep(state.claims)
  })
},
```

Answer (score 10):

This answer is based on [this pretty smart answer by @matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50538743/5599288)

You will need [lodash cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep) function

Basically, create a computed value like this

```js
computed: {
    claimsForWatcher() {
        return _.cloneDeep(this.claims);
    }
}
```

What happens is, everytime a new value is pushed into `claims`, **`claimsForWatcher` will become an entirely new object**.

Therefore, when you watch `claimsForWatcher`, you won't have the problem where *'the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array'* anymore.

```js
watch: {
    claimsForWatcher(oldValue, newValue) {
        // now oldValue and newValue will be 2 entirely different objects
    }
}
```

This works for ojects as well.

The performance hit is exaggerated for the real life use cases till you probably have hundreds (nested?) properties (objects) in your cloning object.

Either with `clone` or `cloneDeep` the clone takes 1/10 of a millisecond as reported with [`window.performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now). So measured under Node with `process.hrtime()` it could show even lower figures.

Comment: This is indeed a bad performance workaround. I'm going to use it till there's a better approach to the solution but won't mark it as final answer to keep this question open. Thank you.

Comment: @JesúsFuentes actually you might not need deep cloning. Depending on what you want to `watch` for, shallow cloning might be enough for you.

Comment: it's opposite:
`claimsForWatcher(newValue, oldValue)`

first argument "new" second "old"

Answer (score -1):

You can assign state to a new object:

```
  mutations: {
    [GENERATE_TX_SUCCESS] (state, generateTxData) {
      state = [
         ...state,
         { transaction: { ...generateTxData } }
      ]
    },
    [GENERATE_TX_ERROR] (state, generateTxError) {
      state = [
         ...state,
         { transaction: { ...generateTxError } }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: This removes the Observers from the state so then, the watch isn't fired.

Comment: If it's the case, you should change to push to `state.data` instead of pushing to `state` directly

Comment: So am I definitely forced to create an object with an array as a subproperty? Is there no other way?