# Change the CSS if dynamically changing image is loaded in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to change the CSS class of a div based on if an image is loaded. The image URL is taken from an `<input>` field, so `<img src>` can change. I've managed to set the CSS class on the first page-load using the `@load` event. But if I change the image's URL in the input field to a non-existent image, then the CSS doesn't change. How do I track if the input's value has changed and "re-check" if the image is loaded?

In the below example, I want to have `green-bg` if the image exists and `red-bg` if the image doesn't exist.

```html
 <div id="app">

    <div :class="imgLoaded ? 'green-bg' : 'red-bg'">
      <img :src=imgURL @load="imgLoaded = true" />
      <br/>
      <input v-model="imgURL" />
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imgURL: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
      imgLoaded: false,
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/veesar/pen/ZEJoMoz)

Comment: I think you're looking for `watch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice place to use a watcher.

```
watch: {
    imgURL(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal !== oldVal) this.imgLoaded = false
    }
  }
```

Hooking to the input event would work too, but there is an edge case where the new value is similar to the old value. If you then set the `imgLoaded` to false, the CSS class won't change to `green-bg` because the load event does not fire (since the url did not change).

When using a watcher you can compare the old value to the new value and only set `imgLoaded` to false if the values are different.

Here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/gijswijs/pen/vYJaWaq).

Comment: Thank you. This works, but how I can change the value of `imgLoaded` if it is in an array. I've got as far as [watching values in arrays](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/watch.html#_3-x-syntax), but not how to update the value. I've [updated your pen](https://codepen.io/veesar/pen/bGrPYVG) with this question.

Comment: With arrays you open yourself up for a world of hurt. I have fixed some issues in your code so that it *does* fire on a changed url, but the problem with deep watching an array is that you can't get the old value of the array, so there's nothing to compare it to. https://codepen.io/gijswijs/pen/abyepea See this answer for a possible solution (by cloning the array into a string and watch that string)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50696834/119129
In the mean time, could you accept this answer as the correct one, since it does answer the initial question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! I've accepted your answer as it does indeed answer the original question: "How do I track if the input's value has changed and "re-check" if the image is loaded?". I'm also linking to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70098751/16094181) which checks if the image exists or not and solves the same problem differently. Is there a difference in performance between the two methods?

Answer (score 1):

Add to you input:

```
<input type="text" v-model="imgURL" @input="updateURL">
```

and create function on methodth section:

```
updateURL() {
    this.imgLoaded = false
}
```

Comment: I couldn't exactly get this to work. `imgLoaded` changes to false but the CSS class did not change. Also `imgLoaded` would not change to true again when input was changed such that @load was true again.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my issue by using the `@error` method. `imgLoaded` would be set to `false` on error and set to `true` on load.

```js
<div id="app">

    <div :class="imgLoaded ? 'green-bg' : 'red-bg'">
      <img :src=imgURL @load="imgLoaded = true" @error="imgLoaded = false" />
      <br/>
      <input v-model="imgURL" />
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

This works for the case where the CSS class is changed based on whether the image exists or not.